# What's the encoding in which Outlook keeps data in a pst file?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, pst

I would like to search a damaged pst file for a certain string in order to recover log-in credentials to a website.

Comment: I tried some commercial data recovery solutions already, but they did not recover the message I am looking for.

Comment: Are the credentials you are looking for in an email? Or are they credentials that Outlook itself was using?

Comment: @eyebrowsoffire They were in an email

Comment: Try http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff385210(v=office.12)

Comment: What external tools have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid the answer is 'it depends'. The PST format is such a all-encompassing format that the implementers didn't prescribe the format for the type of data stored. Only that a piece of data has a type associated with it.

The PST format itself is defined as either ANSI or Unicode. The ANSI version uses 32-bits to represent IDs and the Unicode version uses 64-bits (from Outlook 2003 the default was Unicode). But even that doesn't necessarily help because the strings could be stored as UTF-8, UT-16, or current code page, depending on the data stored. Try both a ASCII search AND a Unicode search using something like [HxD](http://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/). If it's not found using that then it's probably corrupted, encrypted, compressed, or a scary combination of all three. Not sure which external tools you've tried but one of these may work for you:

[Can I access Microsoft Outlook PST archives with any other tools?](https://superuser.com/questions/19555/can-i-access-microsoft-outlook-pst-archives-with-any-other-tools)