# Google Apps Sync bloated PST file to 14GB

Tags: microsoft-outlook, google-workspace, pst, bloatware

**Back story:**
I have Outlook connected to my Google Apps email and noticed that some mail never got migrated from my original PST file. I found some VBA code online that compares mail in different PST folders, modified it to find missing and copy those to the target folder. I ran it folder by folder and moved missing mail. Before the exercise the Google Apps PST was about ~4GB and after it was ~4.7GB.

**Problem:**
I left Outlook open so Google Sync can copy it online. 24 hours later the Google Apps PST file bloated to 14GB+ and none of the mail has been synced to the cloud. I know that there should be at most ~5GB of mail. Why is the rest of the space being taken up? Funny thing is Gmail shows 3GB as being used online.

**What I tried:**
I emptied the deleted items folder and recycling bin 
I've run Outlook compact PST and it didn't work.
I tried SCANPST.exe on the PST and it didn't work.
I re-ran compact PST and it didn't work (after SCANPST found and fixed a few errors)

***Any ideas out there on what caused the problem and how to solve it?***

Answer (score 1):

Try using a 3rd party program (like [Kernel Outlook PST Viewer](http://www.nucleustechnologies.com/pst-viewer.html) or [FileLocator Pro](http://www.mythicsoft.com/Page.aspx?type=filelocatorpro&page=home)) to open the PST and find the 'excess baggage'. Some more tools are listed here:

[Can I access Microsoft Outlook PST archives with any other tools?](https://superuser.com/questions/19555/can-i-access-microsoft-outlook-pst-archives-with-any-other-tools)

If you can find what's taking up the space you might be able to delete it.